# Which SOAP libraries are available for Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, soap, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to deploy an application to Google App Engine that will eventually interface with JIRA and other services over SOAP.  The J2SE 6 java.xml.soap.* APIs are not supported by the GAE JRE.  What other simple libraries are available for building requests and parsing results over a URLConnection?

Axis and CXF seem to be the generally accepted SOAP/Web Services engines, but they seem somewhat overkill for my needs.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

java.xml.soap.* are now on the AppEngine JRE whitelist. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

Comment: the above link has been broken. can you have latest link

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Axis/cxf are overkill for you. They are fairly simple to use, solve the problem and are a standardized solution to solve your problem.

If you can explain why you do think they are so much more than you need, I'll be glad to reconsider